# How to use foreach loop MYSQL month at to add month to +1 month in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I coding MYSQL (reference code to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) to :

```
SELECT * FROM [Orders]
WHERE OrderDate LIKE '1996-01-%'
```

Present result only to show OrderDate of 1996-01-01 to 1996-01-31.

I want result to loop MYSQL month to +1 month in PHP.

> **Example to real result :**
>
> show OrderDate of 1996-02-01 to 1996-02-28
>  show OrderDate of
>   1996-03-01 to 1996-03-31
>  **...**
>  show OrderDate of yyyy-mm-dd to
>   yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Sounds good. Have you made any efforts so far?

Comment: Thanks you to suggestion. I found to answer of solve problem. Use to code : `<?php $y = "aaa"; for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) { echo '<a href="' . $y . $x . '">Test</a><br>'; } ?>` Solve problem easier than to find foreach loop MYSQL month at to add month to +1 month in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this after that you can merge data at programming end

```
select *,max(case when month(OrderDate)=1 then OrderDate end) Jan,
max(case when month(OrderDate)=2 then OrderDate end) Feb,
max(case when month(OrderDate)=3 then OrderDate end) Mar,
max(case when month(OrderDate)=4 then OrderDate end) Apr
from Orders
group by month(Orders.OrderDate)`
```

Comment: Thanks you to suggestion.